DHCP - Windows User machine not taking the IP from Windows Server DHCP
So I am learning windows server administration and this issue is giving me headache from 3 days.
My setup - VMWARE for hosting this machine on my physical laptop.
VM1- Windows Server 2022 with AD, DNS , DHCP(Enabled) - 192.168.1.2 (DC static IP)
VM2 - Windows Server 2022 with AD, DNS , DHCP(Disabled) - 192.168.1.3 (DC static IP)
VM2- Windows 10 Pro User machine - Set to auto receive IP and has proper DNS servers mentioned.
The scope I mentioned in DHCP1 is 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.128
And the address is being leased to the user machine if you see the image below -
Address leased image ss
But on the user machine if I type Ipconfig /all it has an Ip from localdomain 192.168.18.129 instead of 192.168.1.10
ipconfig/all on user machine ss
Now if I ipconfig/release and ipconfig/renew it will give me this error on the user machine -
An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet0 : The name specified in the network control block (NCB) is in use on a remote adapter.
The NCB is the data.
And here is the wireshark dhcp capture logs during this period -
wireshark ss
Somethings which I have already tried, reinstall DHCP , disabled failover and unauthorized the other DHCP server. Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 , I don't know what else to check, ChatGPT and Gemini are both hallucinating.
The VMWare setup for network is using NAT and earlier it worked fine I was able to assign ip's I don't know suddenly what went wrong.

"The VMWare setup for network is using NAT" - Fun fact: NAT-based networks for VMs come with their own DHCP. It sounds like you haven't disabled VMWare's DHCP service first.

Thank you that worked like a charm, disabled the VMWares DHCP service on my vm host machine and then released and renewed the ip, and it took the DHCP ip this time.
